# document.getElementById is returning a null

Tags: javascript, html

When I run it and give  any input number and hit the button it prompts just once. Why is this?

Here is my code:

```
    <html>
    <head> <title> Assignment CS101 </title> </head>
    <script>
    var number;
    var ary;
    var x;  
    function input()
           {
               prompt("Enter","");
               var recieve=document.getElementById('demo');
               number=recieve.value;
               ary = new Array(recieve);
               for(x=0; x<ary.length; x++)
                   {
                     ary[x]=parseInt(prompt("Enter " + x + " name: ",""));
                   }
           }
   </script>
   <input type="text" size="25" id="demo"> <button onclick="input();"> Take input          </button>
```

Comment: It helps to ask a question

Comment: The question is "Why does it only return one time"

Comment: aah that part was just for testing ...

Comment: @PrinceAliRehman it prompts 2 times [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/67UGt/)

Comment: 1. A button (by default) is of type `submit`, so most probably it will submit (refresh) the page. 2. You shouldn't use `Array()` to initialize an array (it has ambiguities), but instead use `ary = []` and replace `ary.length` with `number` in the for loop. 3. You should add the radix parameter as `10` to parseInt, because otherwise it might return unexpected results `parseInt(prompt(...), 10)`

Comment: what do want to achieve with `ary = new Array(recieve);`?

Comment: yes the question is "Why does it only return one time" @mplungjan

Comment: @davidkonrad by ary = new Array(recieve) i want to assign the length of an array

Comment: `Array(recieve)` will always create an array with one element, containing the `#demo` `<input>`

Comment: @devnull69 i tried giving the hardcoded value to the length of array and it works fine on array() but the thing is that i want the use to decide the length of the array,and also i tried the radix thing still no luck

Comment: The solution is easy (as stated by @davidkonrad): You didn't want to have `new Array(receive)`, but rather `new Array(number)`

Comment: yeap now i know my mistake thanks to you guys thanks alot am really grateful

Comment: what should i do if i have to take input like strings e.g danial dave prince etc insted of numbers?

Comment: As a new question. But the answer will involve split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you take the value of the 'demo' which is a string. And try to create a new Array with that string. 
The for loops will run once, because you put a string into it.

```
ary = new Array(recieve);
```

Should use 'parseInt()'

```
number = parseInt(recieve.value,10);
ary = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < number; i ++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a bit unclear what you're going for, but try instead of looping through your array length, loop through your `number` variable

```
for(x =0; x< number; x++)
{
    ary[x] = parseInt(prompt("Enter " + x+ " name: ", ""),10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's prompting only the once because you're referring to the length of `ary[x]` in your `for` loop.  However on the line before your `for` loop, you're defining `ary` as `new Array(receive)`, which will have length 1.

You want to define `ary` as a `new Array()` outside of the function (so it's global).  You can then push values to it with `ary.push(receive)`, assuming that's what you're trying to do (not sure what the purpose of the `prompt` is in that for loop)

Answer (score 0):

you create an array with just one element in it, because the value in the input is a string with digits, but no number yet.

```
function input() {
  prompt("Enter","");
  var number = parseInt(document.getElementById('demo').value,10);
  ary = new Array();
  for(x=0; x < number; x++) {
    ary.push(parseInt(prompt("Enter " + x + " name: ","")),10);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
ary = new Array(number);
for(x=0; x<number; x++)
{
  ary[x]=parseInt(prompt("Enter " + x + " name: ",""),10);
}
```